# How to add an IBM DB2 server to SQL Server's Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, db2, linked-server

From .Net, I'm able to connect to the DB2 database:

1. First I include a reference to "IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries"
2. Then I create a new IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Connection. The connection string is

   ```
   DataSource=ChaDb2Server;UserID=MyUsername;Password=MyPassword;
   ```
3. Then I create an IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Command, and so on.

Now I'm trying to get my SQL Server 2005 to access the same data directly. In SQL Server Management Studio, I right-click on Linked Servers, and select "New Linked Server..."

```
Linked Server:   ChaDb2Server
Provider:        IBM OLE DB Provider for DB2
Product Name:    ???
Data Source:     ChaDb2Server
Provider String: DataSource=ChaDb2Server;UserID=MyUsername;Password=MyPassword;
Location:        ???
```

I can leave Location blank, but Product Name can't be empty and I don't know what to fill in here.

On the Security tab, I select "Be made using this security context" and I repeat the UserID and password.

The linked server gets created, but when I try to expand Catalogs / default / Tables, I get an error message:

```
OLE DB provider 'IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1' reported an error. Authentication failed. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7399)
```

I have no idea where the name IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1 came from.

Also, when I try to select data:

```
Select * from ChaDB2Server.ChaDb2Server.Information_Schema.Tables
```

I get a similar error:

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
OLE DB provider 'IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1' reported an error. Authentication failed.
```

Obviously there's something missing in the way that I link the servers. Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't had luck using the IBM provider. I hear it's tricky.  However, I have successfully used the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers.

My configuration points to a DSN and works well. The only 3 fields I have filled out is the provider (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers), product name (value='not used') and Data Source (name of the DSN on the SQL server).

If you don't mind using the ODBC provider, it will work for you.

Comment: I don't mind using the ODBC provider. But so far, the only way I've been able to connect is using the .NET provider. Do I need to set up "Data Sources (ODBC)" first, in order to use the ODBC connection? I haven't figured out how to get this to work.

Comment: Yes. The data source name is the name of the system dsn you create in 'Data Sources (ODBC)'

Answer (score 2):

The way i setup `DB2 LUW` server as a linked server in `SQL` is the following :

**1-** I installed the appropriate `DB2 LUW` client on `mySQL` Server

```
--> This will installed the missing driver for DB2 (IBMADB2.DB2COPY1)
```

**2-** I create the linked server as follow :

```
replace the <...text...>  with your values

/****** Object:  LinkedServer [<DB2_DB_Name>]    Script Date: 09/08/2014 09:46:02 ******/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'<DB2_DB_Name>', @srvproduct=N'IBMADB2.DB2COPY1', @provider=N'IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1', @provstr=N'Database=<DB2_DB_Name>;Hostname=<DB2 Server running the DB2 database>;Port=5900'
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'<DB2_DB_Name>',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'<DB2_DB_Name>', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'<DB2_DB_Name>', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'<DB2_DB_Name>', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'<DB2_DB_Name>', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'<DB2_DB_Name>', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'<DB2_DB_Name>', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'<DB2_DB_Name>', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'<DB2_DB_Name>', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'<DB2_DB_Name>', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'<DB2_DB_Name>', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'<DB2_DB_Name>', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'<DB2_DB_Name>', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'<DB2_DB_Name>', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I've never had any luck getting linked servers to work when set up through the GUI.  However, I have had success doing it with sp_addlinkedserver.  See here for IBM's instructions on how to set this up: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21394344

Comment: IBM's instructions say, `a typical default installation of DB2 V9 will yield PROGID IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1`. But it doesn't say how to confirm that this is correct! How do I find out what the progid is?

Comment: I think it was confirmed in that error message you got.  It's not the ProgID that's wrong here.  But definitely use that one.