# SQL Server: link DB2 table

Tags: sql-server, db2, linktable

I would like to query a DB2 table in SQL Server. Is it possible to link a DB2 table in SQL Server?

I do not have that much experience with SQL Server and could not find much documentation on this subject. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to query a DB2 table in SQL Server. Is it possible to link a DB2 table in SQL Server?

This is possible by involving **linked servers**

Example of SQL to create a linked server object:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server = 'WNW3XX',
@srvproduct = 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2',
@catalog = 'OLYMPIA',
@provider = 'DB2OLEDB',
@provstr='NetLib=SNA;NetAddr=;NetPort=;RemoteLU=OLYMPIA;LocalLU=LOCAL;ModeName=QPCSUPP;User ID=WNW3XX;Password=WNW3XX;InitCat=OLYMPIA;Default Schema=WNW3XX;PkgCol=WNW3XX;TPName=;Commit=YES;IsoLvl=NC;AccMode=;CCSID=37;PCCodePage=1252;BinAsChar=NO;Data Source=Olympia_WNW3XX'

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'WNW3XX', false, NULL, 'WNW3XX', 'WNW3XX'
```

And a sample query to a remote object on DB2 instance:

```
SELECT * FROM WNW3XX.OLYMPIA.WNW3XX.DEPARTMENT
```

The answer is based on:
[Creating a linked server to DB2 using Microsoft OLE DB provider for DB2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/222937/creating-a-linked-server-to-db2-using-microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-db)

Other references:

- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2151/how-to-create-a-sql-server-link-server-to-ibm-db2/
- http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Tips0013.htm
- [How to add an IBM DB2 server to SQL Server's Linked Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768120/how-to-add-an-ibm-db2-server-to-sql-servers-linked-server)

Answer (score 2):

Starting from SQL Server 2019 CTP 2.0 you could use also **PolyBase**:

> [What is PolyBase?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-guide?view=sqlallproducts-allversions)
>
> **PolyBase enables your SQL Server instance to process Transact-SQL
>   queries that read data from external data sources.** SQL Server 2016 and
>   higher can access external data in Hadoop and Azure Blob Storage.
>   Starting in SQL Server 2019 CTP 2.0, you can now use PolyBase to
>   access external data in SQL Server, Oracle, Teradata, and MongoDB.
>
> The same queries that access external data can also target relational
>   tables in your SQL Server instance. This allows you to combine data
>   from external sources with high-value relational data in your
>   database. In SQL Server, an external table or external data source
>   provides the connection to Hadoop.

[Configure PolyBase to access external data in Teradata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-teradata?view=sqlallproducts-allversions) as example:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL credential_name 
WITH IDENTITY = 'username', Secret = 'password';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE external_data_source_name
WITH (LOCATION = teradata://<server address>[:<port>],
-- PUSHDOWN = ON | OFF,
CREDENTIAL =credential_name);

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ...;

SELECT * FROM external_table_name;
```

---

> [CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sqlallproducts-allversions)
>
> LOCATION = '://'
>
> Provides the connectivity protocol and path to the external data source.
>
> ODBC  odbc    [:port]    Starting with SQL Server 2019 (15.x) - Windows only
>
> [CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=sqlallproducts-allversions)

Comment: Sorry for the possibly stupid question, but how is this related to DB2? And how can I query different tables in my external datasource?

Comment: @Bechi Yes, I agree that the example is unfortunate(it points to Teradata). Polybase could connect to DB2(by ODBC driver). Second - after you create extrernal data source you need to define external tables.